# interfaces and implementation java

Tags: java, interface

In this link  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qjmt.png) , I have some interfaces and I want to implement them. I have a problem because I have an array of IanaRecord according to the relationship of the UML, but **find** method signature of IanaRegistry interface, returns an array of **IanaBaseRecord**.

So, when I try to implement the **find** method, I have an error because when I have found the object that I want, I can't "copy" an IanaRecord object to a IanaBaseRecord object, to return a list of IanaBaseRecord.

[I have uploaded the code with the error I have mentioned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dj4G0.png)

```
....
public class IanaRegistryImpl implements IanaRegistry{  
private List <IanaRecord> lista = new ArrayList <IanaRecord>();
}
....
public Set<IanaBaseRecord> find(String recordType, String descriptionSubstr) 
{
    Set <IanaBaseRecord> foundlist = new HashSet<IanaBaseRecord>(); 
        for(int x=0; x<lista.size();x++) {          
        if (lista.get(x).getTipo().equals(recordType) && 
          lista.get(x).getDescription().equals(descriptionSubstr)){         
            foundlist.add(lista.get(x)); //here I have the problem
        }
        }
return foundlist;
}
....
```

Regards

Comment: can you be more specific..better if you share some code

Comment: yes I can share the code that I have the issue:

Comment: Can you share the code and implementation of lista? As i can not see anything related to this.